# using same buttons many times

Tags: android, user-controls

I have 3 buttons that is **modify ,view, clear** and i want it to be used in 20 activities. I want to re use the same as if in user control in android?
**Button 1- Modify, 
Button 2 - Clear,
Button 3- view.**
Is it good to make common view for all?

Comment: Put them into a fragment and reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your 3 buttons in another layout say layout_button.xml and then include this in ur activity's layout  wherever required like :
For ex. this ur activty layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <-- Inflate your other elemnts of ur activity -->

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
    layout="@layout/layout_button" />
```